# Type error when creating element using jQuery inside IF statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically creating an input element with different attributes depending on a variable value. Without the IF statement the following lines work perfectly:

```
$("<input />")
    .attr("id", "input" + i)
    .attr("type", "checkbox")
    .attr("class", "inline checkbox")
    .attr("checked")
    .attr("data-role", "none")
    .appendTo("#input" + i + "container");
```

However when I use the following, I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...) is undefined

```
var checked = localStorage.getItem(i + "checked");
if (checked === "true") {
    $("<input />")
        .attr("id", "input" + i)
        .attr("type", "checkbox")
        .attr("class", "inline checkbox")
        .attr("checked")
        .attr("data-role", "none")
        .appendTo("#input" + i + "container");
} else {
   $("<input />")
        .attr("id", "input" + i)
        .attr("type", "checkbox")
        .attr("class", "inline checkbox")
        .attr("data-role", "none")
        .appendTo("#input" + i + "container"); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]? I cannot replicate this.

Comment: `.attr("checked")` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.attr("checked")` returns a boolean so it breaks your chaining. You forgot to add the value portion of it.

You can add multiple attributes in one call using an object

```
$("<input>")
  .attr({
    "id": "input" + i,
    "type": "checkbox",
    "class", "inline checkbox"
  });
```

And with jQuery 1.6 you really should be using prop() to set checked.

```
$("<input>")
  .attr({})
  .prop("checked", true) //.prop("checked", false)
```

Comment: Thank you for the additonal comments, I will implement those :)